# Add JavaScript code in React component and calling it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

How to add JavaScript code that I copied from a website in React component and call it using onclick?

this is my code that I copied

```
function myFunction() {
  var hide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (hide.style.display === "none") {
    btnText.innerHTML = "Loadmore";
    hide.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    btnText.innerHTML = "Load less";
    hide.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

I have created a component where I had created a button tag. I want to call the function using onclick. How do I do that?

Comment: Post the full component showing the `JSX` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it inside the component with the `onClick` prop like this:

```
<Button onClick={myFunction} />
```

But if you want to do it with a better practice I recommend you to change the whole function and use [React hooks states](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) instead.

For example:

```
function ReactComponent() {
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = React.useState(false);
  const [textLoadMore, setTextLoadMore] = React.useState("Load more");

    function myFunction() {
        if (!loadMore) {
          setLoadMore(true);
          setTextLoadMore("Load less");
        } else {
          setLoadMore(false);
          setTextLoadMore("Load more");
        }
    }

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={myFunction}>{textLoadMore}</button>
        {loadMore && (<div>content</div>)}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a button tag you can call the onClick event to call the function in the component.

**Note:** You must write onClick with the Capital letter C.

```
function ReactComponent() {

    function myFunction() {
        ...
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => myFunction()}>Button</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: While that addresses triggering a function from the onClick event, the question includes a bunch of DOM manipulation that needs to be replaced with state manipulation and rendering logic.

Comment: @Quentin It really depends. There are situations where it's totally acceptable to just use vanilla JS for DOM manipulations. In this case, it's literally just styling. If it was data, then I would object to this implementation. The react way of doing this is actually quite involved, since there are two dom elements. It'd probably need to be one ref passed down, with a `useImperativeHandle` in the child and two refs in the child or something?? I'd have to actually implement to be sure, but regardless of the solution, it's a ton of work

Comment: The React way of doing it avoids have the changes to the DOM reset because something triggers a re-render of the component.

Comment: @Quentin Which is why I said it depends. You wouldn't want a mix of vanilla and React on the same DOM element. But nothing should ever be discussed in absolutes. It's all tradeoffs. There's no denying that a React-oriented solution is really hard and sometimes it doesn't matter at all

Answer (score 0):

HTML: `onclick="myfunction()"`

React: `onClick={myFunction}`